# Is oprofile still alive and well?

Tags: linux, profiling, oprofile

Is the oprofile project still alive and well?

I know it is still supported in the default linux kernel and that the user space utilities works (at least on the Arch linux I'm running), but the majority of the documentation for it seems to be outdated?

Are there other profilers that does the same job as oprofile on linux, or is it simply a case of everything working well for the last few years? Or does everyone have intel core iGezillion processors?

Comment: A better alternative than oprofile is Zoom: http://rotateright.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lately the momentum seems to be with the "perf" tool, distributed as part of the kernel source package since 2.6.30 or thereabouts. In some sense it's a bit more convenient than oprofile in that you don't need root access to use it, but unfortunately documentation is lacking. See https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/

Comment: A very cool but still very simple example of using perf is: 
perf top -p <pid>
shows a sorted list of what functions <pid> is spending all its time in.